# Better than O(n^2) algorithm to find a missing integer in an array containing 999 of the first 1000 integers

Tags: complexity-theory

Suppose I have an array with 999 cells which contains all the numbers from 1-1000 except one number. what is the best efficient way to find this number? I couldn`t find a better way then O(n squared). The interviewer told me there is a better way. How can i do it?

the array unsorted.

Comment: Calculate the sum of all numbers and compare with expected result.

Comment: At worst-case it is O(n) + O(n lg n) - this is what a database might do (e.g. "sort and merge"), and has a better bounds than O(n^2). But there better ways.

Answer (score 13):

The sum of all the numbers from 1-1000 is a known value.   Calculate the sum of the numbers in your array, and subtract the two, giving you the difference.

[We know that the sum of from 1..n is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_+_2_+_3_+_4_+_%E2%8B%AF) `n(n+1)/2`.  This is a fairly common result in mathematics, but you can derive it yourself if you aren't familiar with it using a variety of techniques.

So, you simply need to sum the numbers in your array, and subtract that value from the value above, and you'll know what is missing.

In code, this would be something like:

```
int findMissing(int [] inputArray) {
    //In the above scenario, inputArray.size() would be 999
    int range = inputArray.size() + 1;   //so, range is 1000
    int expected = range * (range + 1) * 0.5;  //we expect the sum to be 500,500
    int sum = 0;
    for (int x: inputArray) {
       sum += x;
    }
    //the missing number is the difference between what we expected, and what we found
    return expected - sum;
```

This would be an O(n) result.

Comment: Dang, this is what I suggested too. Your just a little quicker. But because he is working on the range 0-99 he will need to adjust for that.

Comment: Why not subtract the numbers from the known value?

Comment: @Jeff Mainly because I felt the above was clearer from an explanatory standpoint. You could implement it with only one local variable if that was a requirement for some reason (see below)

Answer (score 3):

Like that:

```
 int sum = (1000 * 1001) / 2; // sum of the n first integers is: n*(n+1)/2
 for(int i : array) {
    sum -= i;
 }
 return sum;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use summation,
http://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/
and then subtract the sum of all cells from summation.

```
missingDigit = (Summation - totalFromCells);
```